# Name of Property of Functions

Tags: functions

Is there a specific term to describe the following property of a function:

$$f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$$

And if $f(x)$ satisfies this property and is not the trivial functions $x$ or $0$, must $f$ be non-linear?

Comment: Such functions are called "completely multiplicative".  They're pretty important in number theory.

Comment: If $f$ satisfies this condtion, then $f$ is nonlinear or $f(x)=x$. This is because if $f$ is linear then we require $f(ax) = af(x)$ but in general $a\neq f(a)$.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. According to, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function, a "multiplicative" or "completely multiplicative" function's  domain is over the natural numbers only. What if the domain of $f(x)$ is the real numbers? Sorry I neglected to say this earlier.

Comment: Then this would be a `homomorphism'.  This is either a semigroup homomorphism if the domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$ (and likewise with the range), or is a group homomorphism if the domain and range are the non-zero real numbers (or a monoid homomorphism in the first case and $f(1)=1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are describing a [Completely Multiplicative Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletelyMultiplicativeFunction.html). These are often called "Multiplicative Functions" outside of number theory, where that means something slightly different.

For the second part of your question, suppose $f(x)=ax+b$. Then you have $f(xy)=axy+b$ and $f(x)f(y)=(ax+b)(ay+b)=a^2xy+abx+aby+b^2$. So, what values of $a$ and $b$ can you have where $axy+b=a^2xy+abx+aby+b^2$? Well, if we let $x=y=0$, then $b=b^2$, so $b=0$ or $b=1$.

Then, if we have $x=0$ and $y\ne0$, that gives us $b=aby+b^2$. This tells us that if $b=1$, then $a=0$. On the other hand, if $b=0$, then $axy=a^2xy$, so $a=1$ or $a=0$.

So you missed one possibility: if $f$ is linear and completely multiplicative, then $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=1$. Any other completely multiplicative function is non-linear.

Comment: Thanks KSmarts. I was actually thinking of a function taking real inputs (not just integers). Your proof still works for real number arguments to $f(x)$, right?

Comment: @FreshAir Yes, it does.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's called a multiplicative function.

See also:

[Multiplicative Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function)

Let's assume f is linear:

$f(x) = ax + b$

Then assume we have:

$axy + b = f(xy) = f(x)f(y) = (ax+b)(ay+b)$ for all $x,y$

Then:

$axy + b = a^2xy + ab(x+y) + ab$

(and this must be true for all x and y).

Now place some nicely chosen $x$ and $y$ in here like e.g. $(x,y)=(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ and see what you find about $a$ and $b$, and see if you can find such $a$ and $b$ which turn this into an equality which is always true (for all $x$ and $y$). This should be pretty easy to do.

Comment: Thanks peter.petrov. I added a comment under the question pertaining to the domain of $f(x)$. I should have included this in the question earlier.